# How to pass string in android without error- A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released-

Tags: java, android, string, stack-trace, argument-passing

I try to fetch stringBuilder object to the my main activity. I check my json file or parsing codes they works well. However when I try to fetch stringbuilder it gave an error: 
 **A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called**

code for **Server.java** is as below

`

```
public class Server extends Activity {

     static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
public Server(){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray project = obj.getJSONArray("project");

        for (int i = 0; i < project.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject ss = project.getJSONObject(i);
            stringBuilder.append(ss.getString("title") + "\n");
            JSONArray post = ss.getJSONArray("posts");

            for(int j = 0; j < post.length();j++){
                JSONObject posts = post.getJSONObject(j);
                stringBuilder.append(posts.getString("id") +"\n");
                JSONArray tag = posts.getJSONArray("tags");

                for(int k = 0; k < tag.length();k++){
                    stringBuilder.append(tag.getString(k) +"\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        stringBuilder.append("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getString(){

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}


public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("cat.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}}
```

and here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


TextView jsonDataTextView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    jsonDataTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Server s = new Server();
    jsonDataTextView.setText(s.stringBuilder.toString());} }
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but I guess you are closing an I/O stream in a `try` block. If an exception occurs, then the stream is not closed. You should try to add a `finally` block and inside it, write `is.close();`.

Comment: Why does your Server class extend Activity ?

Comment: getAssets wants it @Gorcyn

Comment: @TunahanKunt Just saw that while answering. But why not just pass the MainActivity as a parameter and save it as a `Context` property?

Comment: Actually I'm a beginner in Android dev. so i cannot understand what you mean. Also  interestingly when I restart to android studio it stops the give previous error but now it gives a nullpointerexception at  `is = getAssets().open("cat.json");`
However I already run my codes at another project in the `MainActivity` and it works well. Also i try to get the string with getter but it also not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InputStream` may not be closed in the `try` block of your `loadJSONFromAsset` method, and it should.

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open("cat.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do you want to handle this exception?
            }
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

Note: Something bothers me in your `Server` constructor, in the `catch` block you try to append "error" to your `StringBuilder`. Do you know that here, the `StringBuilder` may not be empty. Indeed in the `try` block, one (or more) attempt(s) to append some string to it may work before something goes wrong at some point.

Note 2: Server as a non Activity

```
public class Server {

    private Context mContext;
    public Server(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        ...
    }
    ...
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        ...
            mContext.getAssets().open("cat.json");
    }
}
```

then in your MainActivity

```
Server s = new Server(this);
```

Comment: When I try to put is.close(); in finally it gave an error and public String loadJSONFromAsset() needs a throws IOException . When did it  now JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset()); gave an error and i need a catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
after that when I run it keeps continue to gave an error.

Comment: Edited. It is ugly, I know... but you'll see a lot of exception handling in `finally` blocks when you'll dive into IO streams. Check this out : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java#IOUtils.closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29

Comment: Yesterday I was working on it 8hours. Thank you Gorcyn now it works. However i cannot understand what context do. Can u explain briefly.

Comment: I don't have enough space in the comment box to do better than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android